# Handling longpress event of views inside scrollview in android

Tags: android

I have a `ScrollView`, inside that I have `LinearLayout` with 4 children. My problem is that my `ScrollView` consumes events and because of that I am not able to long press on my child views. I tried setting `setLongClickable(false)` but it is of no use, if I intercept touch events I'm not able to scroll my `ScrollView`.

Comment: Try this soluction http://stackoverflow.com/a/20593492/1384010

Comment: I want long press of child's not of scroll view

Answer (score 2):

Normally Android uses a long press to begin a drag in cases like these since it helps disambiguate when the user intends to longPress an item vs. scroll the item's container. But if you have an unambiguous signal when the user begins longpress an item, try `getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` from the  view when you know the user is beginning a press. This will prevent the ScrollView from intercepting touch events until the end of the current gesture.(check this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks for reply but my requirement is like this i have linear layout and 4 childs and on long press user will be able to drag them and re arrange there order, everything works fine but if i place my linear layout in scrollview I am not able to drag my views

Comment: Please check the below threads ,There are some good example for drag and drop a view :

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/

Thanks